# Convert string data received from network packet to Structure

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am a newbiew to python and ctypes. what I have is:-

C program:

```
struct query
{
  uint16_t req_no;
  uint32_t req_len;
  uint64_t req;
};

struct response
{
  uint16_t req_no;
  uint16_t status;
  uint32_t value_len;
  uint64_t value;
};

// functions for creating query and response packets using
// above structs respectively, returning char buffer.
char* create_query(//some args);
char* create_response(//some args);
```

I have Created a libquery.so for the above C code. My TCP Server is a C program.
I am trying to create a TCP python client (my project needs it!) for the same.

I can successfully send query and receive data(using functions in libquery.so) from python client.
But when i get response data, I want to convert it to "struct response" type.
I have create a similar "Structure" class in python, but can't get anything out of it.

Please help.

Some code snippet of my Python code:-

```
// some ctypes imports 
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libquery.so')

class Info1(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("req_no",c_int),
                ("status",c_int),
                ("value_len",c_int),
                ("value",c_int)]

header = Info1()

// Did some TCP connection code here and send data to server by calling
// create_query() method, data confirmed to be correct on server side...

# Receive response data
data = sock.recv(512)
header = str_to_class('Info1')

header.req_no    =  int(ord(data[0])) // Works; but I don't want to go this ways..
header.status    =  int(ord(data[1]))
header.value_len =  int(ord(data[2]))
header.value     =  int(ord(data[3]))

print above header values..
```

I tried using :-

```
 def str_to_class(Info1):
    return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], Info1)
```

But don't know how to make it work.

Anybody know how to make it work OR is there any other way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'Info1' does not match C 'struct response'. So I changed in following code.
You can use [ctypes.memmove](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.memmove).

```
from ctypes import *

class Info1(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("req_no", c_uint16),
                ("status", c_uint16),
                ("value_len", c_uint32),
                ("value", c_uint64)]

data = (
    '\x01\x00'
    '\x02\x00'
    '\x03\x00\x00\x00'
    '\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
)
# Assumed data was received. I assumed both server, clients are little-endian.
# else, use socket.ntoh{s|l}, socket.hton{s|l} ....

header = Info1()
memmove(addressof(header), data, sizeof(header))
assert header.req_no == 1
assert header.status == 2
assert header.value_len == 3
assert header.value == 4
```

You can also use [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

```
import struct
data = '....' # same as above
struct.unpack('HHLQ', data) == (1, 2, 3, 4) # '>HHLQ' if data is htonl/htons-ed in sencding part.
```

Comment: With ctypes, you could also use `header = Info1.from_buffer_copy(data)`. With `struct` it may be convenient to define `Info1 = struct.Struct('=HHLQ')`. Then it's `Info1.unpack(data)`. The prefix '=' is for standard sizes and native byte order. You can also force little endian '<' and big endian '>' byte order. For ctypes, it's `BigEndianStructure`.

Comment: Hey falsetru,  Thank you so much for your answer. I tried that and now it is working fine.  @eryksun: I am gonna try from_buffer_copy() method now. Thank you so much for suggesting this way as well. :)